# Tool to make mindmap for test strategy

Tags: test-plan, mindmap

I need to draw a more elaborate Mindmap to present my test strategy to my client. I have no experience of creating mind map with any tool.

Can someone suggest any good mindmap making tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more elaborate mindmap I would suggest [XMind](http://www.xmind.net/).

With XMind you can even create testcases inside your mindmap using its matrix features. There are lots more features like:

- Timeline
- Gantt view
- Filters
- Drilldown

Comment: Looks like a good tool. I would try the free version if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For "pure" mind mapping I would suggest [Freeplane](http://www.freeplane.org) (free and open source). I know people using Freeplane for professional test case generation. Very helpful in this respect are

- extensive scripting support that can be used to support testcase entry and for customized exports
- multiple fields per node that can be used for different purposes: attributes (tabular data), notes, detail

If your primary focus is the generation of presentations then you should probably use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/mindolph/Mindolph , this desktop application provides features that you can create and manage mind map easily.

Answer (score -1):

You may try online service MindMup or desktop ConceptDraw MINDMAP. Though the first one is not that professional and intuitive as ConceptDraw tool, it is free. The second product has a 21-day trial period, brainstorm mode, multiple hyperlinks, export to MS PowerPoint or Web pages and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.